# New venv Virtual Environment acts like another env which already exists [Python]

Tags: python, pip, package, python-venv

I installed a venv named env in this folder:

```
|-- ScreenScraper
|   |-- backend
|   |-- docker-compose.yml
|   |-- env
|   `-- scraper_return
```

When I activate it, it behaves like another env named venv in this folder: (at the end)

```
|-- WebScraper
|   |-- __pycache__
|   |   |-- hello.cpython-37.pyc
|   |   `-- hello.cpython-38.pyc
|   |-- byob-profiles-rest-api-docker
|   |   |-- Dockerfile
|   |   |-- LICENSE
|   |   |-- README.md
|   |   |-- Vagrantfile
|   |   |-- docker-compose.yml
|   |   |-- hello_world.py
|   |   |-- requirements.txt
|   |   `-- src
|   |-- django-markdown-editor
|   |   |-- LICENSE
|   |   |-- MANIFEST.in
|   |   |-- README.rst
|   |   |-- __screenshot
|   |   |-- martor
|   |   |-- martor_demo
|   |   |-- push.sh
|   |   |-- requirements.txt
|   |   |-- runtests.py
|   |   |-- setup.cfg
|   |   |-- setup.py
|   |   `-- venv
```

For example, `pip list` shows me the installed packages from `venv` or `pip install -U pip` returns `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./WebScraper/django-markdown-editor/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (20.0.2)`. Again the empty `env` is activated. Is it a Bug or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: By "I installed" did you mean you've executed `virtualenv env` in the `ScreenScraper` directory? I'm asking, because the behaviour you experience is a frequent symptom if you copied virtual env directory from somewhere else. Check `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable in `ScreenScraper/env/bin/activate` script, it should point to your `ScreenScraper` directory.

Comment: I executed `python3.8 -m venv ~/www/ScreenScraper/env` in the ScreenScraper directory. `VIRTUAL_ENV` points correctly to `VIRTUAL_ENV="~/www/ScreenScraper/env"`.

Comment: Just restarted Debian. When `~/www/ScreenScraper/env` is activated `whereis pip` shows correct path. `pip list` shows packages which are not installed for this venv.

Comment: To list packages from virtual environment, you should use either `pip freeze --local` or `pip list --local`. In other case it is going to display global packages as well.

Comment: Hard to find these command. I´m almost certain it didn´t required the `--local` flag before. Anyways... `python3.8 -m pip list --local` works now. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately the `env` continues using packages from the other `venv`. After attempting to install the required packages in `~/www/ScreenScraper/env` I got from pip `Requirement already satisfied in */www/WebScraper/django-markdown-editor/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/...`.

Comment: Oh, damn, I already posted my answer, but I added one more solution, so please, check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we established in the comments section, your problem is not because of wrongly set up virtual environment, but it's worth mentioning the possible solution for others who might come across this question in future.

The problem with virtual env being invoked from other virtual env directory is a frequent symptom of copying virtual env directory from one place to another. **This should be avoided!** The reason behind that is the `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable hardcoded in `[venv_dir]/bin/activate` script. So, always make sure that this variable points to a valid directory.

#### Solution for OP

In order to list packages from a virtual environment **only**, you need to use `--local` flag either for `pip freeze` or `pip list`. You can find this in the documentation:

> **-l, --local**
>
> If in a virtualenv that has global access, do not list globally-installed packages.

The key phrase is *global access*. The possible reason why pip keeps finding packages that are outside your virtual environment might be the `PYTHONPATH` and `PATH` environment variables. Check them. Whatever you have in those paths will be visible by pip.